# Moshi custom field not working on serialization

Tags: android, json, serialization, moshi

I'm using Moshi 1.8.0 on Android, and I'm following the instructions on the Moshi documentation create custom fields: https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-field-names-with-json

This means that my request data class is like this:

```
data class GetStuff(
        @Json(name = "RequestContext") val context: RequestContext,           
)
```

but the issue is that the actual HTTP request gets sent like this:

```
{"context": "blah... }
```

What I'm expecting to happen is for my request to be like this instead:

```
{"RequestContext": "blah... }
```

This seems to work fine for the response, but I can't figure out how to make it work for the request.

Thank you!
Is this not how the `@Json(name = "")` annotation works for request?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, I'm an idiot.

I'll answer this for whoever needs this in the future (likely me again).

In order to convert Json to an data class, you have to change your API call to be have this annotation:

```
@MoshiDeserialization
```

I knew that, and that's the magic annotation that makes deserialization work.

However, I didn't know I also needed a second magic annotation for the serialization part to work as well:

```
@MoshiSerialization
```

Now it works.

Comment: What are you using to make your API calls? Moshi defines no such annotation.